# Can GDB print the size of structures from a core dump of a C program?

Tags: gdb

I'm using GDB to analyze a core dump of a C program. Is it possible to print the size of a struct in the program?

Answer (score 56):

These should all work in GDB (assuming you compiled with `-g`):

```
print sizeof(var)
print sizeof(Type)
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm: This gives the size of the type for the target program and not for gdb, right?  The two could be compiled for different architectures.

Comment: @DanielWalker Correct: neither `var` nor `Type` may even _exist_ in GDB.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried "sizeof"?

the complier may do the byte alignment automatically by default,so this size may be greater than you think